# Spring Boot Web - Override WebJar resource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, webjars

3rd-party WebJar contains JSP file in the root of `resources` folder. So I can get this page by URL like `http://host/app/target.jsp`

Now I want to override this `target.jsp` in my codebase. I've tried to put this JSP into the root of `resources` folder and also to `resources/static` folder with the same name, but no luck it still using WebJar file.

What tricks should I perform to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have more than target.jsp in webjar? DO you want to override all of them or just target.jsp and expect all other files to work as is?

Comment: I want to override certain resource. But it would be if you can share solution for whole replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new view controller as given below and move custom JSP to another folder.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfigurator extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("target.jsp").setViewName("/custom/target.jsp");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I'm getting an exception that DispatcherServlet can't find the `/custom/target.jsp`. I've tried with `classpath` prefix, but no luck.